# Using Lodash to filter a list of objects by key name

Tags: lodash

I have a list of objects that look like this:

```
[

      {
        "account_id": "1002",
        "fields": [
          {
            "text_value": "2/3/87",
            "name": "birth_date"
          },
          {
            "text_value": "Dennis",
            "name": "first_name"
          },
          {
            "text_value": "Monsewicz",
            "name": "last_name"
          },
          {
            "text_value": "White",
            "name": "socks"
          }
        ],
        "created_at": "2015-10-08T14:31:07.306000",
        "archived_at": null,
        "email": "foo.bar+09202902902942@gmail.com",
        "contact_id": "3bd41146-7157-4bd1-b8dc-b85c5bd765a4",
        "status": "active"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "1002",
        "fields": [
          {
            "text_value": "2/3/87",
            "name": "birth_date"
          },
          {
            "text_value": "Dennis",
            "name": "first_name"
          },
          {
            "text_value": "Monsewicz",
            "name": "last_name"
          },
          {
            "text_value": "White",
            "name": "socks"
          }
        ],
        "created_at": "2015-10-08T14:34:12.874000",
        "archived_at": null,
        "email": "ff.lol+lololpopo@gmail.com",
        "contact_id": "abf0dc16-2e54-45e3-9bed-c0784da645ba",
        "status": "active"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "1002",
        "fields": [
          {
            "text_value": "gibberish",
            "name": "birth_date"
          }
        ],
        "created_at": "2015-10-08T19:56:50.208000",
        "archived_at": null,
        "email": "bar.baz+dksjhfs@gmail.com",
        "contact_id": "ff3ee87a-b7a7-4b1f-98dd-307bf3c10d06",
        "status": "active"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "1002",
        "fields": [
          {
            "text_value": "1",
            "name": "city"
          }
        ],
        "created_at": "2015-10-08T20:02:46.546000",
        "archived_at": null,
        "email": "bar.bax+2dwksjhfs@gmail.com",
        "contact_id": "98b6be26-6fa2-4d8e-8776-2ab300e9a4b0",
        "status": "active"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "1002",
        "fields": [
          {
            "datetime_value": "1987-02-03T00:00:00",
            "name": "birth_date"
          }
        ],
        "created_at": "2015-10-08T19:59:18.189000",
        "archived_at": null,
        "email": "foo.pop+2dksjhfs@gmail.com",
        "contact_id": "59f1bcbf-e62a-4705-bb80-dd96a6fa5976",
        "status": "active"
      }
    ]
```

The above data is being returned by an endpoint in an API I am working on. I am going to allow for a user add in a query param of `filter_columns` where they can return certain information if they like.

So the URL would look like `http://my-api.com/1002/contacts?filter_columns=["first_name", "last_name"]`. I am basically trying to filter out the `fields` array where the `name` equals a column in the filter_columns array. I am trying to play around with the lodash method of `_.matchesProperty` (http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#matchesProperty), but I am unsure how to do what I want do

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a total of 3 iterations to accomplish what you want.

1. over all elements of the `data` you got from the API endpoint
2. over all elements of `fields`
3. over all elements of `filter_columns`

I would recommend this solution :

```
_.each(data, function(i) {
  _.remove(i.fields, function(f) {
    return _.includes(filter_columns, f.name)
  })
})
```

Or with ECMAScript 6 :

```
_.each(data, i => {
  _.remove(i.fields, f =>
    _.includes(filter_columns, f.name)
  )
})
```

`matchesProperty` or callback of similar style would be useful if `filter_columns` was a single string instead of an array. If you had a single string called `filter_value` you could do (total of 2 iterations):

```
_.each(data, function(i) {
  _.remove(i.fields, 'name', filter_value)
})
```

In this case a `matchesProperty` style callback is used and `filter_value` is matched with `name` property